# Barrier is not functioning as expected for constraint layout android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

Looking to achieve this
[image]

The corresponding XML is this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topstrip_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_08"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_top_strip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelAmount"
        style="@style/TextLabelArbitrage"
        android:text="@string/arbitrage.label.trade_amount"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_54"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/labelFees"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/labelFees" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        style="@style/TextContentArbitrage"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_87"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier_top_strip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/labelAmount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/labelAmount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labelAmount"
        tools:text="1000" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelFees"
        style="@style/TextLabelArbitrage"
        android:text="@string/arbitrage.label.total_fees"
        android:textColor="@color/red_400"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/labelProfit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/labelAmount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fees"
        style="@style/TextContentArbitrage"
        android:textColor="@color/red_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier_top_strip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/labelFees"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/labelFees"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labelFees"
        tools:text="1000" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelProfit"
        style="@style/TextLabelArbitrage"
        android:text="@string/arbitrage.label.profit"
        android:textColor="@color/green_400"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/labelFees"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/labelFees" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profit"
        style="@style/TextContentArbitrage"
        android:text="@string/arbitrage.label.trade_amount"
        android:textColor="@color/green_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier_top_strip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/labelProfit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/labelProfit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labelProfit"
        tools:text="10000" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_top_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="fees, profit, amount" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/srcExchange"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_exchange"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/width_exchange"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_strip_grey"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/srcText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/srcText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/srcText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_top_strip"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/srcCoin"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_strip_grey"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/srcExchange"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/srcExchange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/srcText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black_54"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/transfer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/srcExchange"
        tools:text="Sell XRP at Bitbns for Rs.24" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/transfer"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:src="@drawable/transfer"
        android:tint="#D7D7D7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/destText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/srcText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_top_strip" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/destExchange"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_exchange"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/width_exchange"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_strip_grey"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/destText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/destText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/destText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_top_strip"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/destCoin"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_strip_grey"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/destExchange"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/destExchange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black_54"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/transfer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/destExchange"
        tools:text="Sell XRP at Koinex for Rs.25 askdhakjdhakdhakjdhakjdjhakdjakjdahjdkhjadhjak" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However when the content `destText` or `srcText` overflows the `barrier_top_strip` doesn't prevent it resulting in

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Styles for reference

```
 <style name="TextLabelArbitrage">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/medium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/margin_atomic</item>
</style>

<style name="TextContentArbitrage">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/medium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_atomic</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the heights of `destText` and `srcText` to `0dp`. They are now `wrap_content`. This change should constrain their vertical height to the bounds that you expect.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Cheticamp , this indeed does resolve the overflow issue but now my layout vertical packing is messed up and the srcText is occupying all of the space and causing my srcExchange to snap to top. https://imgur.com/a/jUZsFPx

Comment: @humblerookie Take a look at packed chains with bias [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains). I think it will help you solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had earlier tried it with bias, but that doesn't help, do you mind taking this over to chat or would that be borderline pestering? :/

Answer (score 1):

I resolve all my problems with barriers adding this implementation:

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3'